# POSIX-ERE: Match a word but not when between square brackets

Tags: regex, posix-ere

I’m trying to match occurrences of the word “organization” but not when it occurs in between square brackets:

Example strings:

> The **organization** “[organization name]” must contain at least one
>   user per **organization**.
>   The ID [id] for [organization] must contain digits only

I try to use:

```
(?:^|\s)(organization)(?!])
```

but the only flavor supported in the application I'm using is [POSIX Extended](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions) Regex.

Comment: Are you trying to replace?

Comment: Most probably the tool you are using supports returning just what is captured. Try `\[[^][]*]|\b(organization)\b`. To remove those occurrences, use `(\[[^][]*])|\borganization\b` and replace with `\1`. BTW, if it is for AHK, it supports PCRE, not POSIX ERE.

Answer (score 0):

> occurrences of the word “organization” but not when it occurs in between square brackets

The shortest way would be `(?!<\[)(organization)(?!=\])`.

> The only flavor supported in the application I'm using is POSIX Extended Regex.

Since negative lookarounds are not available to you: [`([^[]|^)(organization)([^]]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/lYdiRJ/1).

This fails to match `[organization` and `organization]`; if you want it to succeed when either the open or close bracket is missing, you have to explicitly add those cases:

```
([^[]|^)(organization)([^]]|$)|\[(organization)([^]]|$)|([^[]|^)(organization)\]
```

Comment: This actually matches organization in *[the organization name]*. So not the answer.

Comment: @revo: Good point. This wasn't exactly specified, but I'm tempted to assume that it shouldn't.

Comment: Although it's not within given sample input, the first sentence is generic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right the occurrences in brackets shouldn't match

Thank you for the help!
I finally used this variant:

```
([^\[]|^)(organization)([^\]]|$)
```

I had to escape the [ in the range